# long term replacement for silverlight map control

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, maps

Microsoft are rolling back on silverlight. We quite liked their silverlight map control but its not licenced for China. Any ideas on replacements?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the standard Bing Maps component with data from Nokia Maps or OpenStreetMap. For more info see http://www.developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/Bing_map_API_with_Nokia_Map_and_OpenStreetMap

Comment: Thanks -- it was frustrating trying to ask the question in Google!